# Scale font to size when text exceeds container?

Tags: css, fonts

I want font size to be 54px if the text fits inside the container, otherwise it should be 36px.

I was considering whether I can achieve this with a pure CSS solution, using the scale function to collapse to either of the two. If the container can be assumed to be full with, I guess I could use vw as a base for a calculation?

But I am very much stuck on this. Could anyone give me a hint, as to how I can achieve this or something close to it.

Comment: You can check on which screen resolution container text exceeds and using media query u can change font size for below resolution.

Answer (score 3):

This question awsers was not exactly what I was looking for, so here is a solution to scale down the text if it would exceed the size of the parent container, by making it smaller until it fits the container.

```js
for(const element of document.getElementsByClassName("shrink"))
{
        var size = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
        const parent_width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element.parentElement).getPropertyValue('width'))
        while(element.offsetWidth > parent_width)
        {
            element.style.fontSize = size + "px"
            size -= 1
        }
}
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px dashed #ccc;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px;
}
.shrink{
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span class="shrink">long text to shrink</span></div>
<div class="container"><span class="shrink">small text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to put some text inside a container and have it size itself to fill that container, then CSS Tricks has an article on [Fitting Text to a Container](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) that will cover your options.

You could also use [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) which take advantage of viewport units such as:

- `1vw` = 1% of viewport width
- `1vh` = 1% of viewport height
- `1vmin` = `1vw` or `1vh`, whichever is smaller
- `1vmax` = `1vw` or `1vh`, whichever is larger

One unit of any `v*` is 1% of the viewport axis. Where the “Viewport” == browser window size == window object. If the viewport is 50cm wide, `1vw` == 0.5cm. Using viewport units alone such as `font-size: 4vw;` can make the text appear too big or too small when varying the window width and bring accessibility issues (as the user preferences are not taken into account).

Lastly, you could use `clamp()` to achieve [Simplified Fluid Typography](https://css-tricks.com/simplified-fluid-typography/). Clamp takes three values, a min, max, and a flexible unit in the middle that it will use in case the value is between the min and max.

If you want the font size to be a minimum of 36px and maximum 54px, you could use `clamp()` like this and vary the "flexible unit" to your liking. Here is an example of fluid typography for an `<h1>` element inside a container.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  border: .2rem solid #f06;
  padding: .5rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 36px; /* fallback */
  font-size: clamp(36px, 10vw, 54px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Heading text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Browser support for `clamp()` is pretty good, but you’d probably want to put a `font-size` declaration before it to set an acceptable fallback value.

In conclusion, if you needed to set an explicit `width` and `height` for said container, you might want to use media queries along with viewport units, `calc()`, or `clamp()` depending on the size of the content box in which the text resides.

Comment: I'm curious, why was this answer downvoted? Also, does any of this information help you to accomplish your task? @Luhmann

Comment: Seems to me this is the only working CSS solution here.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's nearly impossible to calculate it without js.

below is an code example how i would do it in jquery or you could use the following jquery plugin, but i never tested this plugin before: [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/blob/master/jquery.fittext.js)

```js
for (let container of $('.text-container')){
    container = $(container);
    let textInner = $(container).find('.text-inner');

    console.log(container.width());
    console.log(textInner.width());

    if (container.width()<textInner.width()){
        textInner.addClass('fs-36');
        textInner.removeClass('fs-54');
    } else {
        textInner.addClass('fs-54');
        textInner.removeClass('fs-36');
    }
}
```

```css
.text-container,
.text-container-before{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #333;
    color: #090;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.text-inner,
.text-before{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0399;
    word-break: keep-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.fs-54{
    font-size: 54px;
}
.fs-36{
    font-size: 36px;
}

/* just added because console window is hiding running code snipped */
.spacer{
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>before</h1>
<div class="text-container-before">
    <div class="text-before fs-54">a bit longer text</div>
</div>

<div class="text-container-before">
    <div class="text-before fs-54">shorter text</div>
</div>

<h1>after</h1>
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text-inner fs-54">a bit longer text</div>
</div>

<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text-inner fs-54">shorter text</div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not, Sure about CSS solution. But, My JS solution can resolve your problem.

Refer below code. Class `class-54` and `class-36` will change based on content:

```js
// creating node
function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

// creating append
function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el);
}

var getPageTitle = document.getElementById("pageTitle"),
  textLengthWidth = 0;
const getPageTitleText = getPageTitle.textContent;
getPageTitle.innerHTML = "";
for (let index = 0; index < getPageTitleText.length; index++) {
  const span = createNode("span");
  span.innerHTML = getPageTitleText.charAt(index);
  append(getPageTitle, span);
  if (index == getPageTitleText.length - 1) {
    calcFontSize();
  }
}

function calcFontSize() {
  var listOfSpan = document.querySelectorAll("#pageTitle span");
  listOfSpan.forEach(element => {
    textLengthWidth += element.offsetWidth;
  });
  console.log("total DIV width: " + getPageTitle.offsetWidth);
  console.log("total Content width: " + textLengthWidth);
  getPageTitle.offsetWidth < textLengthWidth ? getPageTitle.classList.add("class-36") : getPageTitle.classList.add("class-54");
}
```

```css
 * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .title {
            display: block;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        h1, h1 span {
            font-size: 54px;
        }

        .class-54 span {
            font-size: 54px;
        }

        .class-36 span {
            font-size: 36px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="title">
        <h1 id="pageTitle">Hello World! Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this support to work as is in the SO window?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Text size never changes. Content width isn't accurate

Comment: @LarryBud, Please review my updated code and this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/h0n3tu5c/56/

Comment: Still doesn't work. Classes are never applied as I change the size of the window. See the screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w7UTFVz3BE&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score -1):

try `word-break: break-all;`, I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```css
.thingy {
font-size:54px;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="thingy">Hel000000000000000000ooo</h1>
```

Comment: Do suggest why it work. h1 also doesn't break due to a single word.